# How to separate value by using comma my SQL?

Tags: mysql

My table column has rows like this 1001, 1002, 1003 and so on separated by commas. There may be 1 or more comma separated values in each column. I need the total count of these comma separated values in the table. For example if my table has 2 rows one having 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004 and another with 1001, 1005 the output i should get is 6 i.e. 4+2. Kindly assist

Comment: You really should consider [normalizing your data](http://phlonx.com/resources/nf3/), it will make your application *much* easier to build, more maintainable, and (usually) faster.

Comment: Does it have to be in MySQL, or would php (or another server-side language) be acceptable?

Comment: Here's a link to the MySQL String functions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html. I'm seeing functions that will find *where* in the field it can find a comma, but not *how many* commas.

Answer (score 3):

there is no function in mysql to count char occurences. but you can replace every comma with nothing. and then you calculate the difference of lenghts which will give you the number of commas, which is one less than the number of values.

```
select
( LENGTH(col1) - LENGTH(REPLACE(col1, ',', '')) + 1 )
+ ( LENGTH(col2) - LENGTH(REPLACE(col2, ',', '')) + 1 ) 
AS valCount
from T;
```

(didn't test that explicitely but at least something very similar to that will do the job.)

[replace()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)
[length()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length)

Comment: Nice idea.  I think you'll need to sum it and probably will want different columns as different counts, though.

Comment: well he asked for the total count. this would be per row.

Comment: Ok, I see where you were coming from:  He starts by saying "values in each column".  I read it the other way, where his example says he is summing data in 2 rows.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT SUM(LEN(ColumnName) - LEN(REPLACE(ColumnName, ',', ''))) FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those tasks that'd be much, *much* easier in the server-side script accessing your database than the database itself. Assuming you've already assigned the comma-separated strings to an array (where `$array[1]` is equal to the string from row 1:

```
$array = array("1001, 1002, 1003, 1004", "1001, 1005"); // assigned from database
foreach($array as $k => $v){
    $numbersInString[$k] = count(explode(', ', $v));
}
echo implode(' + ',$numbersInString);
```

This is possible, with creative solutions (such as that from [Raffael1984](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695060/how-to-separate-value-by-using-comma-my-sql/6695226#6695226)), in MySQL, but seems to much more easily, and concisely, implemented in PHP.

---

References:

- [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php).
- [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).
- [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).
- [`foreach()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using the count() function?  You can specify which rows if you need to.

```
.row[COUNT(name)]
```

in your query.  What does your table look like? I might be able to help more if I know what it looks like

Comment: COUNT is used to count rows, not the occurrences of commas within the rows.

Comment: I thought he needed to count the number of "numbers" in his rows. If you have a row that specifies where that data is, COUNT will return the number of items

Comment: @Xiphos: OP has a single field that literally contains `1,2,3,4,...`. It's not multiple rows of that field with one value in each field.